# Функция поиска наибольшего угла между соседними треугольниками выдаёт странную ошибку на тесте

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Здравствуйте.
Написал код, вычисляющий наибольший угол между соседними треугольниками и выводящий его в радианах.
Сама функция подсчёта:

```
for k in range(1, n):
    index = ind[k-1]
    index2 = ind[k]
    for index in range(2, m):
        V1 = np.array(coord[index]) - np.array(coord[index-1])
        V2 = np.array(coord[index]) -np.array(coord[index-2])
    for index2 in range(2, m):
        V3 = np.array(coord[index2]) - np.array(coord[index2-1])
        V4 = np.array(coord[index2]) - np.array(coord[index2-2])
        n1 = np.cross(V1, V2)
        n2 = np.cross(V3, V4)
        max = angle_between(n1, n2)
        if epsilon > max:
            continue
        print(float("%.15f" % Decimal(np.pi-max)))
    break
```

На паре известных коплектах тестовых данных выдаёт идеально верные ответы, но когда я скармливаю код электронной проверяющей системе, выводится, что формат вывода неверный. Хотя формат явно верный.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть дело?
Может, я как-то косо максимум считаю? При подсчёте углов юзал [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827393/angles-between-two-n-dimensional-vectors-in-python/13849249#13849249) и [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516296/find-the-normal-angle-of-the-face-of-a-triangle-in-3d-given-the-co-ordinates-of)
С форматом уже всё, что только можно, перепробовал.

Comment: Обычно в "электронных проверяющих системах" есть тривиальные задачки, которые помогают отладить такие вещи как формат выходных данных (сколько знаков после запятой (в первом примере), какая десятичная точка, перевод строк \r\n или \n итд. Внимательно читайте условие, тщательно изучите приведённые примеры (если есть).

Comment: @jfs, так проблема именно в том, что на единственных 2 открытых задачках всё прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 3):

На первый взгляд, угол **3*π/2** больше чем **2*π/3**. Хотя на самом деле это не так.

Поэтому следует проверить диапазон, в котором функция `angle.between` вычисляет углы для отрицательного косинуса (когда они тупые, т.е. самые большие) - возможно, в проверяющей программе есть валидация угла.

Тогда:

1. Можно искать не максимальный угол, а минимальный косинус.
2. Углы **>π** корректировать по формуле

   **angle' = 2π - angle.**

Comment: Negometyanov, cпасибо, звучит интересно, попробую.